# Provider de conexão não está funcionando em VBScript

Tags: sql-server, asp

Tenho a seguinte string de conexão:

```
conn = "Provider=SQLNCLI; Server=" & conn_server &"; Database="& conn_database &"; UID="& conn_uid &"; PWD="& conn_pwd
```

E o código para abrir e executar a SP:

```
set conexao = server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
conexao.ConnectionString = conn
conexao.Open

set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")        
cmd.ActiveConnection = conexao
cmd.CommandText = "sp_login"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@EMA_PES", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, login)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PSW_PES", adVarChar, adParamInput, 35, psw)

set Rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Rs1.CursorLocation = adUseClient
Rs1.CursorType = adOpenStatic

Rs1.Open cmd

session("id_pes") = Rs1("id")

Rs1.Close()
Set Rs1 = nothing
conexao.Close()
Set conexao = nothing
```

O problema ocorre no comando `session("id_pes") = Rs1("id")`. Diz que o item não pôde ser encontrado na coleção correspondente.

Já verifiquei e o comando é executado no banco.
Quando troco a string de conexão para usar o `Driver = {SQL Native Client}` funciona sem problemas.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: `(comentário de um outro utilizador que não tem rep para postar):` Você tem certeza de que tem o SQLCNI instalado no seu servidor?

"Já verifiquei e o comando é executado no banco." que você diz acima, foi verificado pelo log ou você fazendo a query diretamente no banco?

É comum você ter o erro que o RecordSet está vazio quando na verdade o "provider" não foi encontrado.

"provider not found"

Comment: Olá. Foi verificado com o Profiler do SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que vejo em seu código, você está executando a Stored Procedure `sp_login`, e após executa-la tentando capturar um id `Rs1("id")`. O que ocorre é que "aparentemente" (Pelas suas informações) que sua Stored Procedure não está fazendo o "Output" deste `id`.

Seu driver está correto, e o erro que você recebe não tem ligação com a conexão, e sim com a tentativa de ler um dado que não existe no objeto.

Eu utilizo SQL Server 2008R2 com o driver SQLNCLI10.

Seguindo este [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-native-client-use/):

Ao final da página, você tem as versões de SQL Server e ao escolher o banco, seus respectivos drivers.

Comment: O "Output" deve ser diferente dependendo se uso Provider ou Driver na conexão? Como eu disse, utilizando Driver {SQL Native Client} funciona sem problemas.